# calling a stored procedure having out parameter using jpa 2.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Following is the procedure.

```
create or replace 
    PROCEDURE test ( upload_id_in in NUMBER, o in out NUMBER)
    is

    begin

    select  safety_id into o from case_smsw_master where safety_id=111722;

    end;
```

Following is the code to call the procedure.

```
           Query q = em.createNativeQuery("CALL test(?)");
            q.setParameter(1, Long.valueOf(tempCaseId));
            q.setHint("org.hibernate.callable", true);
            Object i=q.executeUpdate();//getResultList();//executeUpdate();
```

Exception is `result set meatadata not found`.
What could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
/**************************************************/
/* Call MYSQL Stored Procedure and MAP it to bean */
/**************************************************/
Query callStoredProcedure_MYSQL = session.createSQLQuery("CALL SP_MYSQL_HIBERNATE (:param1, :param2, :param3)").addEntity(User.class);
callStoredProcedure_MYSQL.setInteger("param1", 10);
callStoredProcedure_MYSQL.setInteger("param2", 10);
callStoredProcedure_MYSQL.setString("param3", "javaQuery");

/* callStoredProcedure_MSSQL.list() will execute stored procedure and return the value */
List userList = callStoredProcedure_MYSQL.list();
if (userList != null && !userList.isEmpty()) {
 for(User user : userList){
  System.out.println("Firstname:"+user.getFirstname());
 }
}

/******************************************************************/
/* Process custom result of Stored Procedure                      */
/* Un-comment the code, This will be the same for MSSQL and MYSQL */
/******************************************************************/
Query callStoredProcedure_MYSQL = session.createSQLQuery("CALL SP_MYSQL_HIBERNATE (:param1, :param2, :param3)");
callStoredProcedure_MYSQL.setInteger("param1", 10);
callStoredProcedure_MYSQL.setInteger("param2", 10);
callStoredProcedure_MYSQL.setString("param3", "javaQuery");

/* callStoredProcedure_MYSQL.list() will execute stored procedure and return the value */
List customResult = callStoredProcedure_MYSQL.list();
if (customResult != null && !customResult.isEmpty()) {
 Object[] obj = customResult.get(0);
 System.out.println(obj[0]);
 System.out.println(obj[1]);            
}
```

Comment: actually my problem is i have to use entity manager ...there i am not allowed to use session object.